# how to change default always on url in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-webapps

Is there a way to change the default *AlwaysOn* url to "/health" instead of "/"  in Azure App Service ( linux )?

[image]

Edit 1 : After enabling the health check, the alwaysOn check triggering to "/" instead of "/health"

[image]

Comment: What is the framework and version of your App?

Comment: Java 8+ Red Hat JBoss EAP 7   @Harshitha

Comment: Enable the Health Check and add the path as shown in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrKfI.png) and check once.

Comment: I have added @Harshitha but I don't see the change in the url for AlwaysOn call from App Service.

Comment: @Harshitha - Do you have idea of change or redirect the "AlwaysOn" URI to custom URI?

Answer (score 1):

1. In the App Service blade, click on the "Configuration" option in the left-hand menu.
2. In the Configuration blade, select "Default Mappings".
3. Add your mapping (/health) and order it to be the first. or try deleting the others if you don't need them.
4. Click on the "Save" button to save the changes.

Comment: I don't see Default Mapping in configuration option. App stack Java 8 + Red Hat JBoss EAP 7

Comment: is it not possible for this app stack ?

Comment: Default mapping is available only for the app deployed in Windows.